# App crashed when getting string from Dictionary (swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I converted a JSON to Dictionary and got some String by

`title = json?.objectForKey("Titel_Live") as! String`

But some times app will be crashed. I cannot reproduce this problem, just get information from crash reports.

Could someone help me and tell why? Thanks

Error at line 163 
[image]

Crash reports
[image: Crash reports]

Comment: Don't force the cast. You should never use `!` when parsing JSON.

Comment: I think your response don't have the data with `key == Titel_Live `

Comment: `as!` forced unwrapped better go for optional chaining.

Comment: Is there other reason? Because the String "Titel_Live" seems to be always there, didn't changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
title = json?.objectForKey(“Titel_live”) as! String
```

This line of code where you are doing force unwrapped (Don't force the cast using !) is the cause means if object with key `Titel_live` dot not find then should be crashed, better go with optional chaining or use gaurd but yes your `Json` does't contain any object with key `Titel_live`(may be spelling mistake or object is array so validate once).

```
//better go like this check if exist or not.
if let t =  json?.objectForKey(“Titel_live”) {
title = t
}
```

Comment: Is there other reason? Because the String "Titel_Live" seems to be always there, didn't changed.

Comment: may be it is there but not as dictionary. currently you are trying to get object for key.

Answer (score 2):

You should not force the casting  to String.

You can try :-

`title = json?.objectForKey("Title_Live") as? String` (if title is optional variable)
if title is not optional then use:

`title = (json?.objectForKey("Title_Live") as? String ?? "")`

Because **objectForKey** will return nil if no value is associated with that key and force casting nil to String fails and causes crash.